# Laravel: GuzzleHttp\Client Unrecognized content encoding type. How to fix this error?

Tags: laravel, web-scraping

Am trying to scrape data from certain websites  and I am getting this type of error. How do i fix it?

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
cURL error 61: Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings. (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function scrape(Request $request){
       $url =$request->get('url');

       $client =new Client();

       $response = $client->request(
        'GET',
        $url
    );

       $response_status =$response->getStatusCode();
       $response_body =$response->getBody()->getContents();

       dd($response_body);
    }
}
```

And here is my route page

```
Route::get('/','MainController@scrape' );
```

Comment: What URL are you using, and what data does it contain(audio/video/picture/text/file)?

Comment: this is the URL am using https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/  containing text

Comment: I would suggest using a http client-tool like postman to test your url. I tested your url with a http-client from phpStorm, and see i get a 403 response:`This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.` This is an issue you most likely have to fix on the url side, it is not per definition an error in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you have saved me